# Laravel combining routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Is there any way of combining these two following routes?

```
Route::get('project/(:any)', 'dashboard.project@(:1)');
Route::get('project/(:any)/(:any)', 'dashboard.project@(:1)');
```

I'm asking because the second route, I had to add it in order for the following requests to work:

```
site.com/project/new => method
site.com/project/view/12351326 => method and parameter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex in the first parameter of the `get()` method to combine those.

See section [Regular Expression Route Constraints](http://laravel.com/docs/routing) in the docs.

Something like this might work:

```
Route::get('project/{name}', function($name)
{
    //
})
->where('name', '[A-Za-z0-9\/]+');
```

Where the regex will match URLs such as `/projects/something/anything`. However that might be too loose - it will also match `/projects/any/number/of/url/segments`. But I believe some more RegEx can help make better constraints to get closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: yes, I am planning to integrate this later (just how facebook does it) with more complex logic, but as time is always an issue because, had to go for the other way... for now

Comment: is `->where()` available in Laravel3? Because it doesn't work for me

Comment: Docs still live [here](http://three.laravel.com/docs/database/fluent). where() does exist, but needs to be on a query object, returned from `DB::table('some_table')`. `DB::table('my_table')->where('id', 1)->get()`

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew, but I had a `docs` bundle copy, and used that one to search information. And that's exactly why I asked if `where` was supported in L3, for routes.