# laravel 5 , passing values from multiple controllers

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send to a view some values from different controllers
Here is my code:

```
Route::get('/add_email','ListsController@index_add_email');
Route::get('/add_email','RepoController@repo_index_add_email');
```

I am trying to display on this page (add_email) values from those two functions. Of course how its now I am getting error because the second *get* will overwrite the first one. How do I mix those two "GET"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel combining routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043745/laravel-combining-routes)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn't support to point same route ('add_email') to different controller.
if you need to do so, handle the logic inside the action you defined.

```
Route::get('/add_email','ListsController@index_add_email'); 
Route::get('/add_email','RepoController@repo_index_add_email');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/add_email','ListsController@index_add_email');
```

Inside ListsController in index_add_email function add this row:

```
with(new RepoController())->repo_index_add_email();
```

btw, make sure to have a read PSR-1 && PSR-2 guides:

PSR-1: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

PSR-2: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the route to redirect to one controller and then call the other controller from the controller called.

For e.g. in routes.php

```
Route::get('/add_email','ListsController@index_add_email');
```

and in ListsController

```
public function index_add_email(...)
{
    // Other code
    // Call RepoController function
    return app('App/Http/Controllers/RepoController')->repo_index_add_email();
}
```

(Assuming that's the correct namespace for RepoController.php)

Although I think this is the easiest option, it does mess with code organization.  You could try working with Events and Listeners, since it would make logical sense here where two different actions are performed during the same event but again, that's simply overkill.